# Button vs input submit font size differences

Tags: css

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 2.75em;
}

button {
  font-size: 2.75em;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit">
<button>
Click me
</button>
```

On OSX. How come a relative font size acts differently on both of these elements, yet neither is being wrapped? How can I make each type of button the same font size?

Comment: Both look identical in Firefox, and also in Chrome (Windows). So what are you talking about?

Comment: Check the JS fiddle that was added.

Comment: Different on mac chrome

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zyca3q6t/

Comment: Both look identical in the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order change the font size of the input you need to add the `-webkit-appearance: none;` to override the platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 2.75em;
}

button {
  font-size: 2.75em;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" />
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: How does this address the question, could you elaborate?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: I've updated the answer – based on exactly the link suggested by  Huangism :-)

Comment: As do I – if you run the code snippet the font sizes are equal

Comment: it looks like you are doing something wrong dear! you down-voted my answer :(, i'll upvote this answer!

Answer (score -1):

add -webkit-appearance: none; to your submit button style

Comment: Does nothing at all.

Comment: what's your browser?